# Windows 10 APP project needs to be deployed error

Tags: deployment, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I just started learning Windows 10 universal application developing. and when I am deploying the project which I created in Visual studio, it's saying "the project needs to be deployed first".

I have checked the Build Configuration manager settings. the checkbox Deploy is checked.

I tried resetting my mobile and it worked. 
but when I am again trying to deploy an application after some changes, its not working and throwing the same error.

Comment: what is set as current platform and configuration? (for example: local machine x86)

Comment: @AlexejSommer thank you. i got it resolved. uninstalling and re-deploying the app worked smoothly